Boy slowly turns to stone in late 80’s/early 90’s teen fantasy
I keep thinking about a novel I read when I was a young teenager or tween in the early nineties. It starts with a family on holiday, the son is the hero of the novel, meets a girl and gradually gets weirder, eventually turning into stone by the end of the book.
I seem to remember folklore (possibly Druid-related) being a central theme. Set in contemporary times, and I think in the UK and by a British author. I’ve not done it justice with this description - I really remember crying my eyes out, feeling shocked and sad at the ending. First time I’d felt moved like that by something I read. Anyone know what it could possibly have been please?

British and folk-lore immediately brings Susan Cooper to mind, but I don't see anything in her oeuvre that fits, though Seaward has a scene with things turning to stone IIRC.
